# Unknown input format: 'x11grab'

Tags: ffmpeg

guys:

I have problems when i compile ffmpeg and run ffmpeg in linux.

My environment:

1: ubuntu 17.10_x64_bit(i don't think the os version is the key)

2: gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-19ubuntu1) 6.3.0 20170618

3: ffmpeg open source code:3.2

first, i download the source code from ffmpeg [official site](http://ffmpeg.org/). I compile this project with there instructions：

```
./configure --prefix=/home/jjh/software/ffmpeg --enable-shared
make
make install
```

and it worked without any error except some warning, then i run:

```
./ffmpeg -h
```

i make sure that it works and output normally.

but i want use ffmpeg to grabbing screen. so i use this construction(o):

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mpg
```

then output error:

```
Unknown input format: 'x11grab'
```

i want to re-compile this project with --enable-x11grab option, btw , so many solution tell me to to this. but when i add this option, i get some errors:

```
Invalid option --enable-x11grab
```

some people says that i should install some libs:

```
libxfixes-dev
sudo apt-get install libxext-dev
```

so i installed these libs, but it always show this error. pls help me.

Answer (score 9):

I believe `x11grab` is deprecated in this version of ffmpeg, though they only write this to `Changelog` in version 3.3.

If you drag a git version of ffmpeg and check `git log`, you can see several commits around Mar 15 2017, `5ed4644d6d` `4fef648d10` and others, which remove  legacy `x11grab` references.

The alternative of `x11grab` is called `xcbgrab` in ffmpeg (higher than 3.2), that can be built with `--enable-libxcb`.

Comment: Thank you, halfelf. I noticed this information in github, and very helpful to me. though i haven't compiled this source code. but i believe that's the point. thanks again.