# Record region of screen using FFMPEG?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, screen-capture

I am looking to record a defined area of the screen at as high FPS as possible. I then need to extract the milliseconds for each frame.

I was looking at FFMPEG and found that it has (or had...) an option called `x11grab`, so I tried the following to record a region of the screen:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1678x1050 -i :0.0+7,53 -r 25
```

It doesn't work: I get an error `Unknown input format: 'x11grab'`

I tried with `xcbgrab` too, but I get the same error of `Unknown input format...`

I have seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919738/unknown-input-format-x11grab), but I am using Windows 10, and it did not help me.

Google tells me that this argument is now deprecated. I cannot find an examples of how to record just a part of the screen.

I want to take a partial screenshot because I need as high a FPS as possible and my assumption is that taking a partial capture will be faster than taking a full screen capture. Is that correct? If not, of course I could take a full screen capture and the crop out region of interest... and if that is the case, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: For Windows, see the gdigrab device - http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab

Answer (score 1):

Like [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) said, you can check out [gdigrab](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab). The example command they give is

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -show_region 1 -framerate 6 -video_size cif -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -i desktop out.mpg
```

And if you want an arbitrary amount of pixels you can use the syntax `-video_size 720x480`

The `-show_region 1` can also be useful, it displays a frame around the area you are recording.

Comment: There is any way to select area manually before recording?

Comment: no idea, haven't used this in a long time. Good luck